# Separate align style for day and date in a cell

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

I have a cell that contains day date  (Mon  11/21/2011). The problem is with the formatting. I want the day part to be left aligned wrt to the cell while date part to be right-aligned.

```
cellApplyToDate.append(_this.WeekDays.getString(applyToDate.getDay()).substr(0, 3) + "&#160;&#160;" + formatDate(data.ApplyToDate));
```

The above code does append data into cell with no formatting.
Pls advise.

Comment: Thats the constraint. Well I'm trying and if able to break the result would post.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cellDate = $("<div style='width:100%; display:inline-block' />");
$("<div style='text-align:left; display:inline-block; width:30%'/>").text(_this.WeekDays.getString(applyToDate.getDay()).substr(0, 3)).appendTo(cellDate);
$("<div style='text-align:right; display:inline-block; width:70%'/>").text(formatDate(data.ApplyToDate)).appendTo(cellDate);
cellApplyDate.append(cellDate);
```

I managed to format it...